# Append Datetime to filename in Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, datetime

hoping you can help with the basic error.
I'm trying to add the current datetime to the filename after doing some basic formatting to a CSV file via DFs in pandas. The code searches for the column "DATETIME" and re formats it. The CSV is too large to open in Excel or another program to adjust it manually. However I cannot get passed the below error and I believe it has something to do with the variable "final" as the **df1.to_csv** line works if I parse an alternative variable.

I am aware that I could use the datetime/time libraries, although the nature of my environment does not have these available as part of the python build (hence using pandas).

Here is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

csv1 = '(Compacted)_TrialCSV_08072020_113107.csv'
shortcsv = csv1[11:-19] 
currenttime = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
final = shortcsv + currenttime

df1 = pd.read_csv(csv1)

# For debugging 
#print(df1)

df1['DATETIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATETIME'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df1.to_csv('(Formatted)' + final, index=False)

print("Datetime Conversion complete")
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVie8.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVie8.png]

Comment: you need to add the file extension try `df1.to_csv(f"(Formatted){final}.csv" index=False)` also please post your stack trace

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I get an invalid syntax error using your suggestion. It points to the closing double quotes where you added the extension .csv (also what is stack trace, I'm new to this!)

Comment: You cannot have colons in the file name, so you need to change `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` to something like `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S')` or `.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')`

Comment: my apologies I missed out a comma `df1.to_csv(f"(Formatted){final}.csv", index=False)` what version of Python are you using `f-strings` were introduced in Python 3.6 @Fred nice point, this is only True of windows, you can use colons on Linux and Mac I believe.

Comment: Nice one Fred that worked! I should have realised that you can't add colons to filenames in Windows. Thanks so much. @Datanoice - Appreciate the help, I am running 3.5.2 hence why it wasn't working. I'll defo look into f-strings tho whenever 3.6 comes into play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S') instead